# What final sentence particle can replace の and is used more commonly by men?

Tags: colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles, gender

の has a female connotation and I wanted to obtain some alternative final sentence particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquial language in females is sometimes characterized by dropping the sentence-final だ altogether to sound less forceful/direct. So the equivalent sentence-end for colloquial male language would be のだ, which regularly (almost always) contracts to んだ in casual contexts.

Answer (score 0):

From Japanese in MangaLand by Marc Bernabe:

よ：a) to sound convining, b) to express an order or a wish

さ: emphasizing effect like ね, but mainly in the area of Tokyo

ぞ： A particle only by men in informal-vulgar language, similar to よ to convey certainty.

ぜ: similar to よ and　ぞ, but a bit "cooler", mainly by young men